# Flutter Firebase database permission denied after successful authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

Using Flutter with plugins firebase_auth and firebase_database.
Authenticating with email and password. 
This is code extract for authentication and handling auth change event. After auth success, code inserts user info into realtime database. Everything works fine if database rules are set to read/write true. But, with standard database write rules (auth != null), app throws DatabaseError: Permission denied. 
It appears that database plugin is not aware of authenticated identity? 
Any ideas what is wrong?

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: _emailC.text,
  password: _passC.text
);
```

then:

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
StreamSubscription<FirebaseUser> _userChangeEvent;
DatabaseReference _usersDbRef = database.reference().child('users');

_userChangeEvent = _auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) {
  setState(() {
    _isAuthenticated = user != null && user.isEmailVerified;
  });
  if (_isAuthenticated && _usersDbRef != null) {
    _usersDbRef.child(user.uid).once().then((
        DataSnapshot data) {
      if (data.value == null) {
        _usersDbRef.child(user.uid).set({
          'id': user.uid,
          'email': user.email,
          'display_name': user.displayName
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I already wrote that rules were standard, but since Andre asked to include them here they are:
These are the rules when everything works fine:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true || auth != null",
    ".write": "true || auth != null"
  }
}
```

These are the rules that result with "permission denied":

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also add your firebase rules to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I found that issue is only on IOS, I figured it must be something wrong with my configuration and that was it. 
After correctly importing GoogleService-Info.plist based on this video: https://youtu.be/3nFIMej3Tvw it worked fine.

Comment: Hi, did this work for you on Android first time? On Android I have an authenticated user and can read from an unrestricted Firebase Db.  If I add rules to constrain access to only authenticated users (".read": "auth != null") then I can't read my data.  Do I need to specifically link my authenticated user to my instantiated firebase database?  Thanks

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything special as long as you have google-services.json in your android/app/src. Also check that it contains api_key entry:  "api_key": [{ "current_key": "##########" }]. For some reason I had to manually add it to my google-services.json.