# Flutter and Firestore does not have user information in request

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

Using [flutter](http://flutter.io), I have installed the [firebase-auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth) and [firestore](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore) packages and am able to both authenticate with firebase auth and make a call into firestore as long as I don't have any rules around the user.

I have a button that calls `_handleEmailSignIn` and I do get a valid user back (since they are in the Firebase Auth DB)

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

void _handleEmailSignIn(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);

    print("Email Signed in " + user.uid);  // THIS works
  } catch (err) {
    print("ERROR CAUGHT: " + err.toString());
  }
}
```

I then have another button that calls this function to attempt to add a record into the `testing123` collection.

```
Future<Null> _helloWorld() async {
  try {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('testing123')
        .document()
        .setData(<String, String>{'message': 'Hello world!'});
    print('_initRecord2 DONE');
  } catch (err) {
    print("ERROR CAUGHT: " + err.toString());
  }
}
```

Now this works as long as I don't have any rules around checking the request user. This works...

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /testing123auth/{doc} {
        allow read, create
    }
  }
}
```

This does not which gives `PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.` when I want to make sure I have the authenticated user I did with `_handleEmailSignIn`.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /testing123auth/{doc} {
        allow read, create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect that the firestore request is not including the firebase user. Am I meant to configure firestore to include the user or is this supposed to be automatic as part of firebase?

Comment: I saw a question with similar behavior recently and there it was a `google-services.json` not put in the right place.

Comment: I believe that is all working because google login also works... Just that the firebase login (email or google signin) user result is not transferred to the firestore request.

Comment: That was also the behavior in the other question.

Comment: If you can find it then I can have a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245019/flutter-firebase-database-permission-denied-after-successful-authentication

Comment: Thanks, had a look and that is just about getting google signin to work... which is ok for me. Only when I invoke the firestore after the firebase auth login does not work when referring \to the request.user

Comment: Also I am trying to get this to work for android first

Answer (score 4):

One thing to note that's not well documented is that `firebase_core` is the "Glue" that connects all the services together and when you're using Firebase Authentication and other Firebase services, you need to make sure you're getting instances from the same firebase core app configuration.

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

This way above should not be used if you're using multiple firebase services. 
Instead, you should always get `FirebaseAuth` from `FirebaseAuth.fromApp(app)` and use this same configuration to get all other Firebase services.

```
FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
   name: 'MyProject',
   options: FirebaseOptions(
      googleAppID: Platform.isAndroid ? 'x:xxxxxxxxxxxx:android:xxxxxxxxx' : 'x:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:ios:xxxxxxxxxxx',
      gcmSenderID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      projectID: 'project-id',
      bundleID: 'project-bundle',
   ),
 );
 FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.fromApp(app);
 Firestore _firestore = Firestore(app: app);
 FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage(app: app, storageBucket: 'gs://myproject.appspot.com');
```

This insures that all services are using the same app configuration and Firestore will receive authentication data.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any special configuration needed for the firestore to do this.

This is all you should need.
Modified from [Basic Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /testing123/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

It seems they check if the `uid` is `null` rather than the `auth` itself. Try this out and see if it works. Also, it seemed that your code was inconsistent as the firestore rule had `testing123auth` and flutter had `testing123`. I'm not sure if that was intentional.

Comment: that's not what OP is asking

Comment: @dark_ruby Could you elaborate? OP asked "Am I meant to configure firestore to include the user or is this supposed to be automatic as part of firebase?" and I thought answered their question by saying no special config was need and added some info that might help solve their problem.

Comment: The question is about the client configuration not the server.

Comment: @dark_ruby the question is about configuration in general and the OP did  include server-side configuration by adding their attempts with firestore rules to the question.

Comment: read the title of the question properly once again, it's about request not having user information included. That can only be included in the client. The question body also already mentions server side configuration. In fact you just copied part of the question in your "answer".

Comment: I answered "There shouldn't be any special configuration needed for the firestore to do this." and elaborated in order to potentially provide a solution to fix the OP's problem. The code that I posted is not directly copied from the original question and I linked a source to further reading to ensure the OP was using the rules correctly. The OP was somewhat speculating what the real issue was with his setup, leading to the misunderstanding. I simply tried to direct him away from that following a short answer to his real question.

Answer (score -1):

I would have suggested to make the rule like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /testing123auth/{documents=**} {
    allow read, create: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Or, better yet, limit the scope of the user:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /testing123auth/{userId} {
      allow read, create: 
        if (request.auth.uid != null &&
            request.auth.uid == userId); // DOCUMENT ID == USERID
      } // END RULES FOR USERID DOC
      
      // IF YOU PLAN TO PUT SUBCOLLECTIONS INSIDE DOCUMENT:
      match /{documents=**} {
        // ALL DOCUMENTS/COLLECTIONS INSIDE THE DOCUMENT
        allow read, write:
          if (request.auth.uid != null &&
            request.auth.uid == userId);
      } // END DOCUMENTS=**
    } // END USERID DOCUMENT
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to check if the user is signed in you should use

```
request.auth.uid != null
```