# Flutter - Firebase Realtime Database on Flutter - denied permission on "auth != null" after user is authenticated

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

On Android and after a user has been signed in I am trying to read some data from Firebase Realtime Db but I am receiving a '-3, Permission denied message.  My security rules are

```
  ".read": "auth != null"
```

If I change my security rules to

```
  ".read": "true"
```

then I can read my data.

After logging the user in, I can get access to my FirebaseUser and it has a uid populated that matches the uid in the Firebase Authentication so it seems like the login part is correct.  I log in as follows

```
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

    //do auth
    var googleAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    var googleAuth = await googleAccount.authentication;
    await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);
```

After waiting for the user to log in successfully, I connect to the database as the following.

```
var firebaseApp = await FirebaseApp.configure(
  name: 'db2',
  options: const FirebaseOptions(
    googleAppID: GoogleSettings.googleAppID,
    apiKey: GoogleSettings.apiKey,
    databaseURL: GoogleSettings.databaseURL,
  ),
);
var db = new FirebaseDatabase(app: firebaseApp);

//get data
var popsicles = new List<String>();
var popsicleRef = db.reference().child('popcicles');
```

var result = await popsicleRef.once();

**Plugins used** (all latest as of 31/5/18)

- flutter version is 0.4.4
- google_sign_in: 3.0.2
- firebase_auth: 0.5.10
- firebase_database: 1.0.0
- firebase_core: 0.2.3

**Edit - added a gist**
Here is a gist of the problem (I'm reading data here instead of writing, my security rules are at the top of the page)

https://gist.github.com/twistedinferno/7bc7c62239e009e5195ed4576e7099e8

[image]

[image]

*I'm unsure where I'm going wrong.  Do I need to link my FirebaseApp or my FirebaseDatabase with my FirebaseUser?*

Comment: Can you also include the authentication code and your database structure? Also the complete rules please (It's possible they are in the wrong place)

Comment: I've recreated the problem in a gist (tested and I get the same permission denied error). I've included the db structure and the rules too.  Thanks

Comment: Any thoughts would be great, either I'm doing something wrong or there is a bug in the plugin stuff...my money is on me ;-)

Comment: I get the same message, but all works never the less. I can read and write from the database.

Comment: I had the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49376476/flutter-and-firestore-does-not-have-user-information-in-request I have not revisited the issue since and there are no answers as of yet, so I hope someone does know what the issue is

Comment: @Tree, thanks for trying this out, I have tried it again and I still can't read when security is auth != null, are your plugin versions the same as mine, any obvious difference in the code?

Comment: Yeah, I am using Firestore. I just saw it. My guess is, try to authenticate with `singInAnonimusly` and see if it works then. If it doesnt work, than it could be issue with plugin. Also, try to add rules for write as well, you can put it to false, but maybe it needs the input.