# Flutter Firebase Realtime Database: "[permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data." Problem

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am having a problem with Firebase Realtime Database(RTDB) with Flutter.
I am using RTDB with anonymous authentication in a project.

Sometimes, when I run the app on either device or simulator, it gives me the error in the title: *[firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.*

If I rerun the app without touching anything, the app runs as expected, without any permission error. I am facing this problem about 1 in 20 or 1 in 30 times.

The original ruleset for my RTDB was (since I am using anonymous sign-in):

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null", 
    ".write": "auth != null", 
  }
}
```

Then I thought this is the problem and changed the rules as, but did not remove the code piece for anonymous authentication:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true, //"auth != null",
    ".write": false //"auth != null",
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It turns out that the problem holds even auth feature is not used. The most important point I realized is that likelihood of the problem increases with decreasing wifi signal strength. I simplified the code as:

```
void main () async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
      .child('otomodels')
      .get()
      .then((DataSnapshot? snap) => otomodels = snap!.value);

  print('It is OK');
}
```

I ran the app on an ios simulator. The logs when the problem occurs are:

- 2021-12-12 15:12:44.915068+0300 Runner[39169:341996] Metal API Validation Enabled
- 2021-12-12 15:12:45.367316+0300 Runner[39169:341996] Writing analzed variants.
- 2021-12-12 15:12:45.410703+0300 Runner[39169:342197] 8.9.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
- ***2021-12-12 15:12:49.494185+0300 Runner[39169:342212] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.***
- ***#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)***
- ***#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)***
- ***#2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:367:43)***
- ***#3      MethodChannelQuery.get (package:firebase_database_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart:74:22)***
- ***#4      Query.get (package:firebase_database/src/query.dart:21:27)***
- ***#5      main (package:myProject/main.dart:29:3)***
- ***#0      MethodChannelQuery.get (package:firebase_database_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart:86:7)***
- ***#1      Query.get (package:firebase_database/src/query.dart:21:27)***
- ***#2      main (package:myProject/main.dart:29:3)***

Comment: Likely answer and solution below. If that doesn't help you solve the problem, edit your question to also include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I found a workaround for my problem. As it is independent of auth feature and has something to do with connecting RTDB with low speed net connection, I restart the state if .get().then() routine catches this error.

Comment: i have the exact same issue @eustun there is a real bug probably with poor wifi signal strengh as well in my case.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to read data from the database before the user is signed in. Since your security rules require that there is an active user, this would cause the rules to reject a read.

Keep in mind that `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` may be `null` initially when the app just starts, so you'll want to listen to `authStateChanges` instead as shown in https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought the point you mentioned might have been the problem, that's why I changed the rules from "auth != null" to "true". I would expect signing-in not to be a problem anymore, but it still might be for the firebase since I did not remove the code pieces for anonymous sign-in. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem and found an answer in another SO thread by [Boris R.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49370248/20459009):
[Flutter Firebase database permission denied after successful authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245019/flutter-firebase-database-permission-denied-after-successful-authentication)

My GoogleService-Info.plist file was not imported properly. Proper importing:

1. Download GoogleService-Info.plist file from Firebase
2. Open Runner in XCode
3. Drag and drop the .plist file under: Runner\Runner (<--- here was my initial mistake, I dropped the file to just Runner)
4. Check "Copy item if needed", "Create groups" and "Runner" and click Finish